# Пикселизация изображения

Tags: ipad, xcode, ios, objective-c, iphone

Стоит интересная задача - получить пикселизированное изображение из исходного фотореалистичного изображения (UIImage - CGImage - ...) . То есть например есть изображение, и необходимо разбить его на пиксельную сетку. Главный вопрос - как определить цвет изображения в каждом пикселе и пересчитать его, чтобы после преобразования этого цвета в фиксированный однотонный (RGB) получилось адекватное исходному изображение.

Задача видимо достаточно комплексная и может ее решение неоднозначно. Буду рад любым дельным комментариям на эту тему.

Спасибо!

Comment: среднее между цветами 8ми окружающих пикселов,
сложить все X, поделить на 8, Прибавить O, поделить на 2...

    XXX
    XOX
    XXX
Думаю так будет верно

Comment: Не уверен понял ли я Вас правильно. Изначально есть фотореалистичное изображение(так наверное будет более понятно обьяснить), поэтому если условно разделить его на пиксели, то в каждом конкретно взятом пикселе будет целая гамма, состоящая из различных оттенков. Как найти средний цвет каждого пикселя и заместить его однотонным (rgb), чтобы после этой трансформации сохранился общий внешний вид картинки

Comment: Вы плохо представляете пиксель, пиксель имеет 3 составляющих цвета и интенсивность каждого из 3 основных цветов(в случае с rgb- красный, зеленый, синий, 0-FF на каждый цвет(читайте описание формата бмп он самый простой и понятный))....

Comment: А маштабирование(из кучи пикселов, с огромного фото, получить под размер экрана), по примеру из моего первого коментария(там упрощено), но в итоге каждый пиксел имеет только 1 видимый цвет, состоящий из 3х(4х) основных..

Comment: Благодарю за комментарий, буду разбираться!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось, поставленную задачу (а также массу смежных) решает библиотека [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage). Крайне рекомендую ее при необходимости быстрой и простой работы с трансформацией и фильтрами изображений.